# What are first and second timing props in CSS animation definition stand for?

Tags: css, animation

What is the second and third time items stand for in CSS animation if written one after another like the below order? Code:

```
.myDiv {
  animation: moveUp 1s 1.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) forwards;
}
```

Here 1s and 1.8s? I looked the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation but the sample (which I saw on internet as working) I wrote above is written not in the same order, therefore I am asking.

Comment: The article you linked to explains that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#description)

Answer (score 0):

The second perimeter define animation relay, your animation will start after 1.8Second

Comment: Animation delay

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).